# Как показать нужный контейнер по дню недели?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

Делаю приложение для показа расписания. Почти все готово, но застрял на моменте с расписанием. При входе на главном экране должен быть контейнер с расписанием по дню недели. Как получить текущий день недели, и показать нужный контейнер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью этого можно получить номер для недели.

```
DateTime.now().weekday;
```

При загрузке приложения, узнаете текущий день недели и в соответствии с ним загружаете нужный контейнер